# Docker помогите настроить сеть

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Всем привет.
Система: Ubuntu 18.04
Решил покопаться в докерах, и столкнулся с проблемой.

Задача такая, создал контейнер nginx, php, mysql, во время запуска контейнер привязываться к локальному адресу 127.0.0.1, но тут проблема локально у меня порт 80 уже занят. Как настроить сеть докера чтоб доступ к контейнерам был по другому ip адресу, к примеру - когда запускаешь в virtualbox машину к ней привязан ip виртуальной сети в итого конфликтов нет.

Мой конфиг:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
nginx:
  # используем последний стабильный образ nginx
  image: nginx:latest
  restart: always
  # маршрутизируем порты
  ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  # монтируем директории, слева директории на основной машине, справа - куда они монтируются в контейнере
  volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
  networks:
      app_net:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.200.10
  # nginx должен общаться с php контейнером
  links:
      - phpfpm
phpfpm:
  # у нас свой образ для PHP, указываем путь к нему и говорим что его надо собрать
  build: ./images/php
  #image: php:7.2-fpm
  restart: always
  # этот образ будет общаться с mysql
  links:
      - mysql
  # монтируем директорию с проектами
  volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./logs/php-fpm:/var/log/php
  networks:
      app_net:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.200.11
mysql:
      image: mariadb:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
      networks:
            app_net:
              ipv4_address: 172.16.200.12
      # задаем пароль для root пользователя
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 88887777
networks:
  app_net:
  driver: bridge
  driver_opts:
    com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
  ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
      - subnet: 172.16.200.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.200.1
```

Comment: `<ip>:<port>:<container port>`, `192.168.0.9:80:80`

Comment: почему версия yml - `2.x`, почему не  `3`? странно это.

Comment: Такая версия была в премьере. Если я указу 192.168.0.9 докер создаст сеть с таким адресом? или как это будет работать? Я так понимаю должен быть виртуальный сетевой интерфейс с определённым адресом.

Comment: нет, это просто пример. Явно сеть создавать не нужно. docker-compose сам создает сети легко и непринужденно. Просто используете другой порт 8080:80. И настоятельно рекомендую использовать, найти примеры актуальной версии 3 для compose файла https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 2):

**Докер - это не тоже самое, что виртуальные машины**. Сервисы объединены  в локальную приватную сеть и "видят" друг друга по именам: nginx, mysql, ...
Инкапсуляция стека и сервисов - это одно из главных преимуществ Docker. Таким образом мы можем запустить разные стеки на одной машине, разные версии ПО, без проблем с настройкой. Не нужно пытаться работать с Docker как с виртуальной машиной. Нужно понять цель, которую вы собираетесь достигнуть.

Если нужно открыть ваш сайт или приложение в браузере, то лучше [использовать прокси](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) или просто другой порт. Если уж так необходимо привязать напрямую к IP адресу, то укажите ваш внешний IP в привязке.
Для производственных сред однозначно нужно использовать proxy (nginx).

[docker-compose ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

```
<ip>:<port>:<container port>, 192.168.0.9:80:80
```

Кстати, чтобы привязать порт именно к `127.0.0.1`, это нужно указать явно - `127.0.0.1:80:80`.  Да и вообще, можно просто другой порт использовать, например `8080:80`.

```
ports:
  - "3000"
  - "3000-3005"
  - "8000:8000"
  - "9090-9091:8080-8081"
  - "49100:22"
  - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
  - "127.0.0.1:5000-5010:5000-5010"
  - "6060:6060/udp"
```

p.s. mysql порт можно "не выводить", просто добавить [сервис](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/) `adminer` в стек

Comment: Суть в том что нужно порты все оставить, а сделать привязку к ip но не локальному

Comment: к какому, вы знаете IP?

Comment: К примеру взять 192.168.10.3, на сколько я понимаю если я указу этот адрес работать не будет, нужен сетевой интерфейс в этой подсети

Comment: Да, это должен быть адрес на вашей машине.

остановите сервис, который занимает 80 порт. Например: `systemctl stop nginx apache2` и попробуйте запустить снова ваш стек. 

Узнать ваши ip можно командами: `ip a`, `ifconfig`