# Docker-compose. Проблема проброса порта наружу

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь сам разобраться (выучить, понять) Docker.
Скачал docker-compose.yml, подправил что знал. Вопрос, при запуске **docker-compose up -d** все запускается, с машины докер-хоста через **curl** до **freescout-app:** достучаться могу. Но снаружи нет. Вот ответ **docker ps**:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
dceca72b5bc8   tiredofit/freescout   "/init"   22 hours ago   Up 16 minutes   80/tcp, 2020/tcp, 9000/tcp, 10050/tcp   freescout-app
7ebf127d90a0   tiredofit/db-backup   "/init"   22 hours ago   Up 16 minutes   2020/tcp, 10050/tcp                     freescout-db-backup
0d22a7a85607   tiredofit/mariadb     "/init"   22 hours ago   Up 16 minutes   2020/tcp, 3306/tcp, 10050/tcp           freescout-db
```

```
version: '2'

services:
  
  freescout-app:
    image: tiredofit/freescout
    container_name: freescout-app
    links:
    - freescout-db
    volumes:
    ### If you want to perform customizations to the source and have access to it, then uncomment this line - This includes modules
    #- ./data:/www/html
    ### Or, if you just want to use Stock Freescout and hold onto persistent files like cache and session use this, one or the other.
    - ./data:/data
    ### If you want to just keep the original source and add additional modules uncomment this line
    #- ./modules:/www/html/Modules
    - ./logs/:/www/logs
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=freescout.example.com
    - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=freescout.example.com
    - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@example.com

    - CONTAINER_NAME=freescout-app
    
    - DB_HOST=freescout-db
    - DB_NAME=freescout
    - DB_USER=freescout
    - DB_PASS=freescout

    - SITE_URL=https://freescout.example.com
    - ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
    - ADMIN_PASS=freescout
    - ENABLE_SSL_PROXY=TRUE
    - DISPLAY_ERRORS=FALSE
    - TIMEZONE=America/Vancouver
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  freescout-db:
    image: tiredofit/mariadb
    container_name: freescout-db
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - ROOT_PASS=password
      - DB_NAME=freescout
      - DB_USER=freescout
      - DB_PASS=freescout

      - CONTAINER_NAME=freescout-db
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  freescout-db-backup:
    container_name: freescout-db-backup
    image: tiredofit/db-backup
    links:
     - freescout-db
    volumes:
      - ./dbbackup:/backup
    environment:
      - CONTAINER_NAME=freescout-db-backup
      - DB_HOST=freescout-db
      - DB_TYPE=mariadb
      - DB_NAME=freescout
      - DB_USER=freescout
      - DB_PASS=freescout
      - DB_DUMP_FREQ=1440
      - DB_DUMP_BEGIN=0000
      - DB_CLEANUP_TIME=8640
      - COMPRESSION=BZ
      - MD5=TRUE
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always


networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Спасибо.

Comment: «Но снаружи нет» — вероятно, надо уточнить, что в данном случае подразумевается под «снаружи».

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856264/178576

Comment: Не совсем понял аналогию. Может я не правильно изложил мысль: Веб-сервер на freescout-app запускается. Он необходим только в пределах внутренней сети. Внутри сети есть DNS запись: fr.str.local - 192.168.0.200 (IP докер-хоста) (в реальном yml файле не example.com а fr.str.local).

Comment: обратите внимание на директивы networks и ports.

Comment: Именно там я и спотыкаюсь. Как пробросить порт с 192.168.0.200 (IP докер-хоста) на 172.18.0.3 (IP имиджа).

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Благодарю Вас за содействие и, тем не менее, я так и не понимаю почему когда я пытаюсь зайти по адресу fr.str.local (с другой машины, но из той же сети) ничего не открывается. По моему разумению, запрос должен придти на докер-хост, а там уже должен быть переброшен на freescout-app. Кстати, ss -lt не показывает прослушку на 80-м порту докер-хоста.

Comment: Чтоб докер знал, что нужно пробрасывать порт именно в контейнер сервиса freescout-app нужно добавить опцию ports к сервису в компоуз файле, как написано в ответе по первой ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной конфигурации отсутствую пробросы портов.
Более подробную информацию о том, что это такое и как настраивается, можно найти в [официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ports).

Для сервисов, к которым необходим доступ "снаружи" необходимо делать пробросы портов.

Например, для сервиса `freescout-app` можно добавить проброс `80` порта добавив в конфигурацию сервера следующие опции:

```yaml
ports:
- "80:80"
```